# What is !+[]+!+[] in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi i was reading a article and found pretty strange results the below code in javascript return 2.

```
!+[]+!+[]
```

Can anyone please explain.

Comment: Actually, it returns 2: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZQC6/

Comment: I get `2` myself. Because an empty array cast to a number by `+` is zero, `!0` is `true`, which is cast to `1`. `1+1 = 2`.

Comment: Ug, not another one of these.

Comment: Does someone have a good "How does JavaScript typecasting work?" reference question that all these could be closed as duplicates of?

Comment: In what context did it return 9 for you? How did you test it? What article were you reading?

Comment: It returns 2. i just did not notice the question..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Breaking down the expression into the correct order of operations, you have:

```
(!(+[])) + (!(+[]))
```

First things first, `[]` is cast to a number by `+`, which results in `0`. Don't ask me why, it just does :p Probably buried in the specification somewhere.

`!0` is simply `true`

So you end up with `true + true`, which again casts to numbers, resulting in `1 + 1 = 2`

To get nine, you'd need nine repetitions:

```
!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[] == 9
```

Comment: @j08691 It's okay, I can't count XD